# Date format on OpenX API addCampaign method

Tags: php, api, date, openx

I'm creating a campaign through the OpenX API, and so far so good *but* i need to set an end date to the campaign, via the endDate parameter; the thing is: i don't know what i should bind to the parameter on the API call. I tried using this: `$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . $date_threshold));` where `$date_threshold` is something like `"+1 month"`, but the endDate won't appear on the OpenX panel.

What kind of data do i need to bind to that parameter so it's correctly inserted on the OpenX database? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad you got it to work -- Just as a note: I'm not sure how you handle the general XML-RPC communication, but what I do is pass a date string into PEAR's XML-RPC, something like:

new XML_RPC_Value('20100413T00:00:00', 'dateTime.iso8601')

Comment: where do I get XML RPC Lib? Is there any non PEAR based?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it is a simple `DateTime()`, so nothing of that would work, because the API wants a Date object, not string!

So, the code i sent on the question turns into:

> $date = new DateTime();
>
> $date.modify($date_threshold);